# Bash adding numbers from 2 word in line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I am making a script that accepts a line of input like this

```
 Dave: 1 2 3
```

and outputs the sum of the numbers in this format in terminal

```
 Dave: 6
```

All is well UNLESS the first word is a number... In certain cases. If the number is 1 digit, then output is as expected. Ie:

```
 1: 1 2
```

outputs

```
 1: 3
```

BUT if my first word in the line is a 2 digit number, and the least significant but does not equal 0, the script incorporates that value in the sum. eg:

```
 12: 1 2 3
```

becomes:

```
 12: 8
```

as the least significant value '2' is also added to the sum.

Here is my code and I have highlighted the problematic line.

```
#!/bin/bash
filename=/dev/stdin
sum1=0;
re='^[0-9]+$'


if [ $# -gt 0 ] ; then
    if [ -e $1 ] ; then
        filename=$1
    else
        filename=/dev/stdin
    fi
fi

#sed '/^$/d' $filename

while read line ; do    

    name=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
#   numbers=$(echo $line | wc -w)

    if [[ $name =~ $re ]] ; then
        #VVVVV PROBLEMATIC LINE
       numbers="${line[@]:1}"
       ^^^^ PROBLEMATIC LINE
       for i in $numbers; do
            sum1=$(($sum1+$i))
       done

        printf $line
        echo ' '$sum1
        sum1=0
    else

        for p in $line ; do
            #echo $line
            sum1=$(($sum1+$p))

        done
    #print first word of line here!
        if [ "$line" != "" ] ; then 

            printf $line 
            echo ' '$sum1
        fi    
        sum1=0
    fi
done < $filename
```

Sorry if my code is bad, I am a noob at Bash

Answer (score 0):

This is getting all of the line after the first character:

```
   numbers="${line[@]:1}"
```

I think you want something more like:

```
numbers=$(echo $line | cut -d ' ' -f 2-)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making things too hard on yourself. Since you have the colon as a delimiter between name and numbers, use that as the delimiter for `cut`.
No need for regular expressions, as long as everything after the colon are numbers.

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [[ $# -ge 1 && -f $1 ]]; then
    filename=$1
else
    filename=/dev/stdin
fi

while read line; do

    name=$(echo $line | cut -d ':' -f 1)
    numbers=$(echo $line | cut -d ':' -f 2)

    declare -i sum=0
    for n in ${numbers}; do
        (( sum += n ))
    done

    echo ${name}: ${sum}

done < ${filename}
```